# When will achievements I earn while playing offline update?

Tags: achievements, dungeon-hunter-2

I just got [Dungeon Hunter 2](http://www.gameloft.com/iphone-games/dungeon-hunter-2/) on my iPhone 3G and I have a Mage: Shadowmancer level 22.

I usually play offline when I'm not home and I just noticed that if I play offline and "win" some Achievements, when I go online they are not updating. Does anyone know if they will ever update?

For example, I got the 10,000 Gold Achievement while offline, and now I have around 22,000 but still not "won" in Game Live section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok!

So, it seems that they updated I don't know when but they did. You just have to be patient (3-4 days in my case).

Problem solved!